# How can I modify just the first letter of a String?

Tags: java, string

I have got a `String` which reads `"You cannot sit on that " + entity.getEntityType().toLowerCase() + "!";`. Which returns an upper case, which is why I convert it to lower case.

However, how can I get the first letter ONLY, and turn it into an upper case?

A one-liner solution would be preferred, however beggars cant be choosers.

Comment: _beggars cant be choosers_ StackOverflow is a place where experts selflessly try to help others. While the asker reserves the right to choose the answer, he is expected to show some respect. If you want to make code challenges you may post them in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/. However you will have to do better than this.

Comment: @Krumia I am a beggar because I cannot do methods outside of what java allows. If java does not allow me to do a one-liner like I asked, then I have no power over that. Therefore, in that sense, I am a beggar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In java, if you do any manipulation to String, it will create a new string in the memory.

Here's, how to do it:

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

Comment: One thing to be noted is that the original String is not modified. A new String will be created with the first letter capitalized.

Comment: @TheLostMind: That is correct. I will add this information in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's more efficient to treat the first character what it is - a character and not a `String`:

```
String output = Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(0)) + input.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing it came to my mind was this

```
        int x = a.codePointAt(0)-32;

        a=a.replace(a.charAt(0), (char) x);
```

Comment: This is a trap. What will happen when the first character is a number, or a Unicode character from a non-English language?

Comment: I understood it was only Strings that contained Characters.

Comment: @tudoricc "7" and "ü" are also Characters and at least "7" will result in nonsense with your method, as it has no uppercase (it will become the end of transmission character). For "ü" it works, but what about chinese characters?

Comment: Do chinese characters have upper-case?

Comment: I don't know, but they will be converted to _something_ anyways

Answer (score -1):

You can just use something like this:

```
String output = input.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
```

On the other hand is isn't bad to take a look at the guava libraries.

```
String output = CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, entity.getEntityType()));
```

For this case only it will be overkill but it has a lot of other usefull utilities (Not only for String manipulation)